# Opening accordion link in a website scrolls everything up

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I made an accordion for FAQs for a website I am working on. Every time I click on a link(question) a content (answer) should show up.
Everything work as expected other than once I click on the link and when the content shows up the whole page scrolls up which makes it very annoying.

```css
.FAQ {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: var(--main);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container3-5 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.accordion-item {
  background-color: #283042;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.accordion-link {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #283042;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.accordion-link ion-icon {
  color: #e7d5ff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.accordion-link .down {
  display: none
}

.answer {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #212838;
  transition: max-height 650ms;
}

.answer::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: #8fc460;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.answer p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.accordion-item:target .answer {
  max-height: 200px;
}

.accordion-item:target .up {
  display: none;
}

.accordion-item:target .down {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="FAQ">
  <div class="container3-5">
    <h1>FAQs</h1>
    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item" id="qestion1">
        <a class="accordion-link" href="#qestion1">
                        Question 1....?
                        <ion-icon class="up" name="arrow-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-icon class="down" name="arrow-down-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </a>
        <div class="answer">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, facilis iure! At autem quasi exercitationem laudantium fugiat dolore esse. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, facilis iure! At autem quasi exercitationem laudantium
            fugiat dolore esse.
          </p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item" id="qestion2">
        <a class="accordion-link" href="#qestion2">
                        Question 1....?
                        <ion-icon class="up" name="arrow-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-icon class="down" name="arrow-down-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </a>
        <div class="answer">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, facilis iure! At autem quasi exercitationem laudantium fugiat dolore esse. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, facilis iure! At autem quasi exercitationem laudantium
            fugiat dolore esse.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item" id="qestion3">
        <a class="accordion-link" href="#qestion3">
                        Question 1....?
                        <ion-icon class="up" name="arrow-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-icon class="down" name="arrow-down-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </a>
        <div class="answer">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, facilis iure! At autem quasi exercitationem laudantium fugiat dolore esse. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, facilis iure! At autem quasi exercitationem laudantium
            fugiat dolore esse.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item" id="qestion4">
        <a class="accordion-link" href="#qestion4">
                        Question 1....?
                        <ion-icon class="up" name="arrow-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-icon class="down" name="arrow-down-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </a>
        <div class="answer">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, facilis iure! At autem quasi exercitationem laudantium fugiat dolore esse. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, facilis iure! At autem quasi exercitationem laudantium
            fugiat dolore esse.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item" id="qestion5">
        <a class="accordion-link" href="#qestion5">
                        Question 1....?
                        <ion-icon class="up" name="arrow-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-icon class="down" name="arrow-down-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </a>
        <div class="answer">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, facilis iure! At autem quasi exercitationem laudantium fugiat dolore esse. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, facilis iure! At autem quasi exercitationem laudantium
            fugiat dolore esse.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I made your code runnable, but seemingly, your mentioned problem is not there, could you demonstrate it more?

Comment: Why don't you just use javascript, for example for every element onclick="animation()"

Comment: try `onclick="return false;"` in all of you `accordion-link`